# How do I get my delete button to remove data from database?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

I have a delete button which when clicked it prompts user for conformation. It suggets it is working but when I check the database the data is still there. 
How do I get my delete button to remove data from the database?

```
<?php
// build query
$sql= "SELECT blogID, title, made_by, description FROM blogs";

// execute query
$res=$mysqli->query($sql);

// get multiple results
while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

$blogID=$row['blogID'];
$title=$row['title'];
$made_by=$row['made_by'];
$description=$row['description'];
?>

<form action = "post_action.php" method="POST">

<div style="text-align:left">
<div class="row">
  <div class="leftcolumn">
    <div class="card">
     <td><?php print($title);?></td><br>
    <td> <?php print($description);?> </td> <br>
    <td><?php print($made_by);?> </td><br>

<?//Create edit, comment and delete buttons for each blog?>

    <button onclick="window.location.href = 'edit_blog.php';">Edit Blog </button>

    <input type = "hidden" name="blogID" value= "<?php print($blogID);?>" >

    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Insert Comment"/>

    <input type="submit" onclick="deleteme(<?php echo $row['blogID']; ?>);" name="action" value="Remove Blog"/>

    <? //Javascript code?>
 <script language="javascript"> //inserts javascript code
 function deleteme(delid)
 {
 if(confirm("You're about to delete this blog. Click OK to continue or click cancel.")){ //opens an alert window asking the user if they're they want ot remove the blog
 window.location.href='post_action.php?del_id=' +delid+''; //If they click OK then it'll run the delete function on post_action.php
 return true;
 }
 } 
 </script> <?//ends javascript code ?>

</form> 
    </div>
```

This is post_action.php

```
<?php
include("_config.php");

debug($_POST);
if($_POST['action'] == "Remove Blog"){
$query = "DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blogID={$_POST['blogID']} LIMIT 1";

header ("Location: blog_test.php");
} 
?>
```

Comment: You are sending a GET parameter as part of the URL but try to read a POST parameter in the backend.

Comment: By the way, using GET to modify state on the server is extremely dangerous. Anybody could just point a script at the endpoint and enumerate all IDs which would delete them. It might not even be malicious - a web crawler might try to index these pages automatically and you'd end up with an empty table.

Comment: You didn't execute the DELETE query.

Comment: Try using prepared statements https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp I found this more useful then the php docs

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not execute your delete action. Execute your delete query to remove the data to your database.

`$mysqli -> query($query)`

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in `$_POST['blogID']`.

You are redirecting the user and passing the blog id in the query string, so it should be `$_GET`. Also the key is `del_id` and not `blogID`.

So in post_action.php, do

```
<?php
include("_config.php");

debug($_POST);
if($_POST['action'] == "Remove Blog"){
$query = "DELETE FROM blogs WHERE blogID={$_GET['del_id']} LIMIT 1";

header ("Location: blog_test.php");
} 
?>
```

***PS: I am really worried about if you should delete something this way.***